# (MS Access Automation) How to use the methods of the DoCmd object (VBA) to run Microsoft Office Access actions from c++ application

Tags: c++, vba, ms-access, visual-c++

I need to use methods of [DoCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd) object in my c++ program like AddMenu(), ApplyFilter(), Beep(),
BrowseTo() and [all other methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd#methods).

This project is quite old and before that it used a wrapper for the DoCmd class by calling its methods through InvokeHelper, after updating Ms Access, the wrapper class no longer works, maybe the interface has changed or something, besides, I can't understand where the file is, which is my wrapper class wraps because there is nothing in the dependencies and there are no imports.

BTW the methods in wrapper class look like this

```
void CWRAPPER::AddMenu(const VARIANT& MenuName, const VARIANT& MenuMacroName, const VARIANT& StatusBarText)
{
    static BYTE parms[] =
        VTS_VARIANT VTS_VARIANT VTS_VARIANT;
    InvokeHelper(0x3e9, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms,
         &MenuName, &MenuMacroName, &StatusBarText);
}
```

I have no idea where invoked method located.

Are there other ways to call actions in microsoft access using c++ or is there any library to do this?

**Update** I found DoCmd object inside msacc.olb located in MS Access folder, I managed to generate a new wrapper by 'MFC class from TypeLib', my vs version is 16.11.31, but I was not able to do it in Class Wizard so I did it from 'Add New Item' view.
Now I going to test it.

Comment: Are you using COM through ATL?

Comment: @Dai No, Im not

Comment: ...so how is the existing C++ code calling into Access' COM automation (i.e. VBA) functions?

Comment: I updated the question, it uses InvokeHelper to invoke methods

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944755/visual-c-invokehelper-function

Comment: I have a problem that the wrapper no longer works at all, I cannot call its methods no more.

Comment: Just to confirm, this isn't a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue? i.e. you didn't update a 32-bit MSAccess to x64 MSAccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be as stupid as possible, I simply did not have rights to execute macros... In the options of MS Access, I went to the Trust center and allowed macros to run and enabled other actions.